# How to check an empty JSONArray in swiftyJSON

Tags: swift2, swifty-json

I have a JSON that have a JSONArray as a value in one of the json inside it. here is the example of it.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "symptoms" : [{\"key\":\"sample1\",\"value\":5},{\"key\":\"sample2\",\"value\":5}]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "symptoms" : [{\"key\":\"sample3\",\"value\":1}]
  },
  { "id": 3,
    "symptoms" : []
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "symptoms": [{\"key\":\"sample4\",\"value\":1}]
  }
]
```

So what I am doing is that I am parsing the inner JSON and place it in a String Array. But whenever I look up to `symptoms` it skips the empty JSONArray. So whenever i print the String Array it goes like this (with the given sample on top) `["sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4"]`. But i want to do is to append an `""` to the String Array whenever the JSONArray is empty so it should be like this `["sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "", "sample4"]`. Anyone can help me with this? Here is my code

```
var arrayHolder: [String] = []
var idHolder: [Int] = []
for item in swiftyJSON.arrayValue {
    idHolder.append(item["id"].intValue)

    //for the inner JSON
    let innerJSON = JSON(data: item["symptoms"].dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    for symptoms in innerJSON.arrayValue {
        arrayHolder.append(symptoms["key"].stringValue)
    }
}
print(idHolder) // [1,2,3,4]
print(arrayHolder) // ["sample1","sample2","sample3","sample4"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if `innerJSON` is empty:

```
for item in swiftyJSON.arrayValue {
    idHolder.append(item["id"].intValue)

    //for the inner JSON
    let innerJSON = item["symptoms"].arrayValue // non need to create a new JSON object

    if innerJSON.isEmpty {
        arrayHolder.append("")
    } else {
       for symptoms in innerJSON {
           arrayHolder.append(symptoms["key"].stringValue)
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this one! didn't know about the `isEmpty` method. Im going to accept this answer in 20 secs.